# Django отправка писем

Tags: python, django, email

В Django есть функция по оправки писем. У меня вопрос, можно сделать название какое-то вместо почты, например, как у YouTube? В настройках почты вроде бы капался, что-то делал, но не работает. А еще, если есть БЕСПЛАТНАЯ функция по отправки писем в django, то зачем покупать различные сервисы? Может быть там какие-то дополнительные функции?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Можно конечно, в шаблоне сделать ccылку, где указать нужный адрес:

```
<a href="send/email/">сheckforyon.news@mail.ru</a>
```

a в urls.py

Привязать ссылку из атрибута href к классу или методу,
где и происходит отправка почты.

```
path('send/email/', SendEmail.as_view())
```

Можно вообще сделать красивую картинку, нарисовать лого, рядом адрес почты.
Погуглите как сделать кликабельную картинку.